# MacBook Pro screen went out, have an external monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My MacBook Pro screen went out but I have an external monitor. Any ideas on how to get the main screen on the external without being able to see system settings?

Answer (score 0):

Open the lid of your Macbook Pro, connect the external monitor, power on and then wait untill load login screen.
Close the lid and it should switch the display to the external monitor.

Comment: Thanks. It goes into clamshell mode, open sys settings/displays but because the computer isn't recognizing it's screen, option for mirror setting not offered as option, yet on start up, it goes to extended display. Now my question is, if I connect another monitor & set it to mirror, will it stay that way or will it revert to extended when second monitor is disconnected? Apple could have saved me a lot of grief if they offered the option with only one display.